# NGINX - Access port via SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, elasticsearch

I have ElasticSearch and NGINX set up on my server. Accessing it via SSL is failing.

I can access ElasticSearch fine via:
http://ipaddress:9200
http://mydomain.co.uk:9200

The domain was then set up with an SSL letsencrypt cert.
https://mydomain.co.uk - loads fine
https://mydomain.co.uk:9200 - does not load

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection
mydomain.co.uk sent an invalid response.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

Based on this response, I think NGINX is not letting any traffic through to that port.

- No server firewall enabled.
- Digital ocean firewall enabled but port and my IP address is whitelisted.
- As it mentions, seems more of an SSL misconfiguration issue (or lack of).

Here is my nginx conf for mydomain.co.uk

```
server {

  root /var/www/mydomain.co.uk/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name mydomain.co.uk www.mydomain.co.uk;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
  if ($host = www.mydomain.co.uk) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  if ($host = mydomain.co.uk) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name mydomain.co.uk www.mydomain.co.uk;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**My attempts to resolve:**

#1

```
listen 443 ssl;
listen 9200 ssl;
```

#2

```
listen 443 9200 ssl;
```

#3
I duplicated the 443 server block and changed to 9200.

```
server {

  root /var/www/mydomain.co.uk/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name mydomain.co.uk www.mydomain.co.uk;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  listen [::]:9200 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 9200 ssl; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.uk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.uk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

After every attempt I refreshed nginx and it failed:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

It's the default port for ElasticSearch so I presume that handles it to some extent. When I first added ES I had to go in this file and uncomment `http.port: 9200`

`/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

```
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
network.host: 206.189.29.75
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
```

Comment: I've done the same a few years back, but then your 3rd method was the solution. Can you try it wihtou listening on IPv6 (without `listen [::]:9200 ssl ipv6only=on`) only with `listen 9200;` (no need the ssl)

Comment: @Bert - Tried attempt #3 again with the ipv6 line removed and port 9200, no luck. `nginx -t` comes back as ok but when restarting nginx I get the same `nginx.service` failed message.

Comment: Can you show us the log of NginX? A `systemctl status nginx` woud be nice too.

Comment: I'd guess that ES is still listening on port 9200 and nginx can't bind to it? configure ES such that is listens on localhost:19200 for example and then proxy from nginx to that address.

Comment: Oh sh*t, Phillip is right. If EL is listening on 9200, then you'll never be able to do what you want to do this way. What you need is a new location and proxy_pass it to 9200.

Comment: just because I'm nice: how do you ensure noone messes with your elasticsearch? it seems to me like you are opening it up to the world - which is a really BAAAAAD idea if it's not going to be secured by some authentication mechanism.

Comment: I'm going down the "get it working first" approach. This is purely development for now then I'll secure. But also I am using DigitalOcean firewall to prevent any access to the IP/Port if not whitelisted.

Comment: @Bert - Would I need to create a new `server {` block still too or a `location {` block inside the top `server {` block which has 443 inside.

Answer (score 1):

An example NginX config would be like this:

```
server  {
    listen  80;
 
    server_name mydomain.co.uk;
 
    return 301  https://mydomain.co.uk$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen  443 ssl;

        server_name     mydomain.co.uk;
        root            /var/www/mydomain.co.uk/html;

        error_log       /var/log/nginx/mydomain.co.uk/error.log;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/mydomain.co.uk/access.log;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.uk/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.co.uk/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA;
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload";
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        client_max_body_size 20M;

        index           index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /el {
                proxy_pass http://ipaddress:9200;
        }
}
```

I think this could work. Could you test it?

Comment: I made one change which is to use `/` instead of `/el,` else ElasticSearch thinks I am searching for the word `el`. So, now mydomain.co.uk displays the default ES page on https which is amazing! One final thing but this is a little more specific to my set up to be fair. You can go to `https://mydomain.co.uk` fine, but requests from my site are sending to: `https://mydomain.co.uk:9200` (because I use the ElasticPress plugin which forwards requests to the defined ES server) which then return: `POST https://mydomain.co.uk:9200/ net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: Keep the proxy_pass to HTTP and not HTTPS. Your ES have no clue about the SSL, thus it reports an error when the communication is sent to it via SSL.